# truffle migrate: Accessing 2_deploy_contracts.js of another Truffle project

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration

I am executing “truffle migrate” command  but I am getting one reference error related to ‘adoption’ variable:there is no error related to compilation

## 2_deploy_contracts.js

ReferenceError: ***adoption*** is not defined
    at module.exports (absolute path/2_deploy_contracts.js:5:20)
    at Migration._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/migration.js:56:1)
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
Truffle v5.1.27 (core: 5.1.27)
Node v8.10.0

The 2-deploy_contracts.js of this project is given below which does not have any adoption variable defined:

```
var attacker = artifacts.require("Attacker");
var victim   = artifacts.require("Victim");

module.exports = function(deployer){
   deployer.deploy(adoption);
   deployer.deploy(victim);
};
```

I have defined adoption variable in another 2_deploy_contracts.js file which is given below:

```
var adoption = artifacts.require("adoption");

module.exports = function(deployer){
   deployer.deploy(adoption);
};
```

Somebody please guide me why I am getting this reference error. I am running 'truffle migrate' from the root of the project

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what the issue is. In the line

```
deployer.deploy(adoption);
```

you are using a variable which was not declared previously. You can add

```
var adoption = artifacts.require("adoption");
```

to the top of the file if you have the `adoption` contract defined in that Truffle project. If you haven't defined it there, you will have to copy it over from your other project.

Comment: Sorry, I am not using "adoption" variable in my current 2_deploy_contracts.js, I don't need this line: "deployer.deploy(adoption);" I needed this line in my PetShop project but I don't need this line in my current project which is not Petshop, why should I define it?

Comment: @zak100 Well if you don't need it, remove the line. Maybe it was supposed to say `attacker`?